# Awk to analyse file

Tags: perl

Need some help on this
Here what I have and want to do
This is my file called file.txt

```
Sequences   times       Ip1     ip2     Protocol        info
1       2   10.18.19.12 12.29.29.18 udp     hsahdsdd
2       4   10.13.15.67 12.28.29.19 tcp     blabla
3       7   10.12.27.28 12.17.281.19    udp     hkkkljkl
```

I would like to (using Awk)

- Count how many line I have and print that info + all the protocol name found in a output file called protocol.tx
- Count the lines of IP1 and add the liste of all Ip in another output file called ip.txt

Thanks
Here what I try

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$fname = $ARGV[0];
open(FILE, $fname) || die ("cant read \n");
while($ligne=<FILE>)
{
chop ($ligne);
my ($No, $time, $Ip1, $Ip2, $Proto, $info) = split (/ /, $ligne_);
}
system("awk '{print \$6}' $fname");
system ("awk 'END {print NR}' $fname") >line.txt;
```

Comment: huh? Why do you want to use `awk` (from within a Perl program) to do this?

Comment: It's preferred to use `chomp` over `chop` for newlines.

Answer (score 3):

That form of `system` takes a shell command, so

```
use autodie qw( system );
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

system(shell_quote('awk', 'END {print NR}', $fname) . ">line.txt");
```

but it's silly to use `awk` from within Perl to do this trivial job.